# From an ubuntu GUI application (e.g. Geany), can I "Save As" but with sudo?

Tags: sudo, gui, geany

I ran geany without sudo.  I opened a file (jail.local) and modified it.  Now I can't save it back to the original file.  Is there a way to execute a [menu] command (e.g. File/Save) "as super-user"?

Comment: @Anwar I don't think it's the same.

Comment: @OP you can just copy the text, close the file without saving, reopen with sudo and paste the edited text in.

Comment: geany doesnt allow running as root. ( at least in new versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is specific to **Geany**, the answer is No. Geany has no option to dynamically switch to the role of a privileged user. The only viable option is save the changes to another file (possibly with same name) using the **Save As** feature and then move the file back to original location using `sudo mv` replacing the original file. That will do the job of saving.

But, if you're looking for any generic GUI application that will allow you to save as root without opening it first as root, there is Sublime Text 3.

Sublime Text has a feature which will ask you root password when you want to save edits made on system files, even if you originally started it as a normal user. You may consider it in place of geany from now on.

Comment: Perfect!  I downloaded and sublime text https://www.sublimetext.com/3 then http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt and I now see that when I try to save a file that requires elevated permissions I get the enter super user prompt.  Cheers!

Comment: Really! That's too handy an option